# Kernel Module: No printk messages showing. Is init function being called?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have a simple module, written as follows:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int __init hellomod_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG, "Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hellomod_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG, "Goodbye, world!");
}

module_init(hellomod_init);
module_exit(hellomod_exit);
```

and

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7        7        7        7
```

so that any level messages should output.

The module loads and this can be verified with *`lsmod`*, however no output is produced when loading or unloading the module and checking *`dmesg`*.

I have tried replacing `KERN_DEBUG` with lower levels and still no output, so I don't think the log level is the issue.

How else can I verify the `hellomod_init()` function is called? If it is not being called, what is my error?

I am running and compiling against kernel version 4.6.1-2 on Arch Linux.

Comment: No comma after `KERN_DEBUG`, just `KERN_DEBUG "Message"`.

Comment: Oh that's embarassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a comma after `KERN_DEBUG`. So it should look something like this:

```
static int __init hellomod_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```